# How to Migrate JAVA6 EJB based Application to OpenJDK 13?

Tags: java, migration, ejb, java-6

I need to Migrate my Oracle JDK 6 application to openJDK 13.
what are the changes may required and what are the challenges i may face and how to deal with it and how to build & deploy the project.

***Current project structure is:***
**JDK 1.6,
Ant - build tool,
jboss-5.1.0.GA**

is it possible to migrate this application?

Comment: You will also need to migrate JBoss/WildFly to a version that supports Java 13. This will be the bigger challenge. But why don't you simply download the latestet Wildfly and deploy your EAR or WAR?

Comment: before deploying it in wildfly i need to compile and Build my code with OpenJDK 13. when i'm trying this im getting some Errors. like javax.rmi.* package is not available. How to overcome it.???

Comment: You have to add the missing libraries. Please post all the errors you get. It's hard to help without concrete problems